# Unable to fetch required data in SQL Server using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following data in one of my tables:

```
Id  subpartID     MainpartID    EngagementName  HashValue   Version CreatedDate ModifiedDate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   IN-2022         111112         name1         hash1        1     2022-05-26  NULL
2   IN-2022         111112         name2         hash2        2     2022-05-26  NULL
3   JP-2022         221112         name3         hash3        1     2022-05-26  NULL
4   JP-2022         221112         name4         hash4        2     2022-05-26  NULL
5   AU-2022         221112         name5         hash5        1     2022-05-26  NULL
```

I want to fetch records from it. When I enter a `MainpartID = 111112`, I want the output to be something like this:

```
Id  subpartID     MainpartID    EngagementName  HashValue   Version CreatedDate ModifiedDate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2   IN-2022         111112         name2         hash2        2     2022-05-26  NULL
```

and when I enter `MainpartID = 221112`, I want the output to look like this:

```
Id  subpartID     MainpartID    EngagementName  HashValue   Version CreatedDate ModifiedDate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4   JP-2022         221112         name4         hash4        2     2022-05-26  NULL
5   AU-2022         221112         name5         hash5        1     2022-05-26  NULL
```

What the logic here is that for a particular MainpartID, fetch all subpartID's and then in the final output show only the latest version of a particular subpartID.

My code is:

```
SELECT *
FROM egTable
WHERE egTable.[Version] = (SELECT MAX([Version]) 
                           FROM egTable 
                           WHERE MainpartID = '111112' 
                           GROUP BY subpartID)
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Can someone help me with this? Data is dummy.

Comment: Which column actually lets us know which subpart is the latest?  You seem to have a tie in your sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i think its the version column.

Comment: @BagusTesa Not enough.  For `221112` there are two records tied with the same version.  Which column(s) break that tie?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the `subpartID` for both version 1 is different (one is `JP`, the other one is `AU`). i think, this is why op tried query to get latest version by grouping the `subpartID`.

Comment: yes @BagusTesa u r right. we want latest version of every `subpartID`. @Tim please take a look at desired output in question u will get better idea.

Answer (score 3):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MainpartID, subpartID
                                 ORDER BY Version DESC) rn
    FROM egTable
)

SELECT Id, subpartID, MainpartID, EngagementName, HashValue, Version,
       CreatedDate, ModifiedDate
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY MainpartID, subpartID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is smilar to how you structured it, but you had to 'correlate' the subquery, ie you had to tell the subquery to run for a particular MainPartId and SubpartId. Also you had to filter the mainquery (if you wanted only one MainPArtID):

```
SELECT *
FROM egTable egt1
WHERE egt1.MainPartId='111112'
  and egt1.[Version] = (SELECT MAX([Version]) 
                        FROM egTable egt2
                        WHERE egt2.MainpartID = egt1.MainPartId
                          and egt2.SubPartID = egt1.SubPartID
                        )
```

Incidentally, each time you run the query for a different MainPartID you can of course provide the exact MainpartId to the subquery, in the manner you did.